# Batch File display correct answer to missed answer

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to figure out how to write a batch file line that gives the correct answer to a question when the player answers it incorrectly.

Here is the first line of the game that we are doing.

`SET /p quest1= 1. What was the Six-Million-Dollar Man's first name?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /p quest1=" 1. What was the Six-Million-Dollar man's first name? "
echo %quest1%|find /i "Steve">nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (echo Right answer!) else (echo Incorrect answer, was Steve Austin.)
pause>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

set /p a=what is 2 + 2: 
if "%a%" NEQ "4" (echo sorry, the answer is 4)